# System function doesn't output anything

Tags: c, pipe

I've been tinkering around pipes and parent-child communication, only now I used a `system` function call to pass something from the child to the parent. Problem is I believe `system` doesn't really have any output in my example.

The parent reads input and sends it to the child to check if the string is of "sorted letters". Characters would have to be in lexicographic order. I used `system` to combine `echo` and `grep` and send that result back into the pipe. I was able to narrow it down to the parent's read-end of the the pipe; it blocks. I'm guessing that's because there is nothing in the pipe to be read and the write end isn't closed. I understand that would be the cause of the problem, for that to make sense, `system` would not have to output anything.

```
  /*
$ ./grep
AeIoU
Yes.
blah
No.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>


#define     STRING_SIZE 128

static void     fatalError(char* message);          
int     checkIfAlpha(char   *string, int length);   //f-ja koja proverava da li se string sastroji samo od slova

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    pid_t   pid;
    char    input[STRING_SIZE];     //cuvamo input string ovde
    char    command[100 + STRING_SIZE];
    int     pipeToParent[2], pipeToChild[2];
    int     n;
    char    tmp[50];
    int     count;


    if (pipe(pipeToParent) < 0)
        fatalError("pipe error");

    if (pipe(pipeToChild) < 0)
        fatalError("pipe error");

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        fatalError("fork error");
    else if (pid == 0) {
            //child
        if (close(pipeToChild[1]) < 0)
            fatalError("close error");

        if (close(pipeToParent[0]) < 0)
            fatalError("close error");

        if (dup2(pipeToParent[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
            fatalError("dup2 error");

        while (1) {

        if ((count = read(pipeToChild[0], tmp, 50)) < 0)
            fatalError("read error");
        fprintf(stderr, "2\n");
        if (count == 0)
            break;
        sprintf(command, "echo '%s' | grep -i ^a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$", tmp);

        if (system(command) < 0) 
            fatalError("system error");

        fprintf(stderr, "3\n"); 

        }

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);


    }

    //parent

    if (close(pipeToParent[1]) < 0)
        fatalError("close rror");


    if (close(pipeToChild[0]) < 0)
        fatalError("close error");

    while(fgets(input, STRING_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {

        input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';


            if (checkIfAlpha(input, strlen(input)) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Samo slova\n");
                continue;
            }
            if (write(pipeToChild[1], input, strlen(input)) != strlen(input))
                fatalError("write error");
            printf("1\n");

            if ((n = read(pipeToParent[0], input, STRING_SIZE)) < 0)
                fatalError("fatal error");
            printf("4\n");

            if (n == 0)
                printf("No\n");
            else if (n > 0)
                printf("Yes\n");

    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}


static void     fatalError(char *message) {
    perror(message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int     checkIfAlpha(char   *string , int   length) {

    int c = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (!isalpha(string[i])) {
            c = -1;
            break;
        }

    return c;
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I would've posted the outputs if I thought they would be that significant, but by all means.

Here's the output (with the right input):

```
./grep 
abcde
1
2
3
```

Here's GDB:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe058) at grep.c:23
23  {
(gdb) next
34      if (pipe(pipeToParent) < 0)
(gdb) 
37      if (pipe(pipeToChild) < 0)
(gdb) 
40      if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
(gdb) 
42      else if (pid == 0) {
(gdb) 
76      if (close(pipeToParent[1]) < 0)
(gdb) 
80      if (close(pipeToChild[0]) < 0)
(gdb) 
83      while(fgets(input, STRING_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
(gdb) 

85          input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
(gdb) 
88              if (checkIfAlpha(input, strlen(input)) == -1) {
(gdb) 
92              if (write(pipeToChild[1], input, strlen(input)) != strlen(input))
(gdb) 
94              printf("1\n");
(gdb) 
1
96              if ((n = read(pipeToParent[0], input, STRING_SIZE)) < 0)
(gdb)
```

Comment: (a) You have not stated what input reproduces whatever problem you are seeing, nor what output you obtain, nor what output you expect. (b) Your statement of the problem is that “Problem is I believe system doesn't really have any output in my example.” Your belief is not actually a programming problem. You need to clearly state what the program is doing differently from what is desired, with specifics about how that is observed. (Is it output to standard output? Viewed in a debugger?)

Comment: I'm not sure why one would write low-level code that uses `pipe()` and `dup2()`, then use a problematic high-level function like `system()`.

Comment: When `grep` doesn't match anything, it doesn't print anything. So there's nothing for the parent to read.

Comment: Amending my above comment, it looks like you have given us sample input, in a comment. (I presume “./grep” is the path to the executable of your program? You may want to avoid naming executables with the same name as standard or common programs, as it can give rise to conflicts at unexpected times.) However, what output do you get? What do you want instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` does not write a terminating null character. After `if ((count = read(pipeToChild[0], tmp, 50)) < 0)`, the program passes `tmp`, without writing a null charactering into it, to `sprintf`.

This results in the `echo` command being passed additional garbage data from `tmp` beyond what was read from the pipe, which in turn causes `grep` not to find a matching string.

One fix would be to change the `read` to `read(pipeToChild[0], tmp, sizeof tmp - 1)` and insert `tmp[count] = 0;`.

Comment: Apparently `read` is making a lot of confusion for me. If read doesn't know what byte it's reading, why would it ever stop ? the `read` manual says that less bytes could be read than specified. I'm guessing that's because there were less bytes than attempted to read. If `system` outputs nothing and by nothing I suspect 0 bytes, why would the `read` on the other end ever block when it should return with 0  ?

Comment: @monolith937: `read` knows what byte it is reading. It does not need a null terminator for that. The reason `read` may provide fewer bytes than were written has to due with how streams, pipes, or I/O generally is implemented—buffers and other issues may mean data has to be transferred in pieces. In your program, you should issue multiple read calls (accumulating the pieces of data into one buffer) until you see some end-of-data indicator. For example, the parent might send a newline character to mark the end of a line. However, between your own parent and child, you can choose the method.